# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers! in Java 7

Tags: websphere, java-7, bouncycastle

I want to use BouncyCastle provider in JDK7, so added bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar and want to do encryption using x509certificate I have but,

I am getting this error in IBM WebSphere even if I have updated policy files in jre from here 
https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/mrs/DownloadList?source=jcesdk&lang=en_US

I downloaded unrestricted policy files.

Still I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:250)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Base64Conversion.encrypt(Test1.java:202)
    at Base64Conversion.execute(Test1.java:171)
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
    at javax.crypto.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers!
    at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b$0.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace your policy file with Sun distr. ? IF not try this JDK 7 of Sun : 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce7-downloads.html